# Git command "git svn rebase" not working with XCode 4.3.1

Tags: xcode, macos, git, git-svn

I have cloned few SVN Project on my system, I used to do "git svn rebase" to sync them up with SVN Repositories. Now after updating XCode to version 4.3.1, this command stopped working.

Executing "git svn rebase" on my mac (v 10.7.3) gives me error "git: 'svn' is not a git command".

I suspect, Apple is no longer installing git-svn with new XCode. Do anybody has any idea, how to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the command-line tools with Xcode 4.3?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed "command line tools" from XCode > Preferences > Downloads > Components

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure git-svn never came included in the command line tools but I might be wrong. Anyhow, that's not the point, use [macports](http://www.macports.org/) (or any alike, it just happens I use this one) to get it installed:

```
$> sudo port selfupdate
$> sudo port variants git-core
```

Here you're shown the different variants for a given port (in this case git-core), and amongst them there is the one we need:

> ...
>
> svn: Bi-directional subversion repository support
>
> ...

We install it by typing

```
$> sudo port install git-core +svn
```

And off you go, you should be able to use git-svn again!